# Не удаётся получить данные из локальной базы данных в текстовые поля

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, android-room, viewmodel

Есть фрагмент `DescriptionFragment`:

```
class DescriptionFragment : Fragment() {

    private var binding : FragmentDescriptionBinding? = null
    private val descriptionViewModel : DescriptionViewModel by viewModel()

    val position: Int = getArguments()?.getInt("position", 0) ?: 0

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_description, container, false)

        binding?.name?.text = descriptionViewModel.loadDescription.value?.get(position)?.name
        Log.d("OnClick", "name во втором фрагменте " + descriptionViewModel.loadDescription.value?.get(position)?.name)
        binding?.date?.text = descriptionViewModel.loadDescription.value?.get(position)?.date
        binding?.description?.text = descriptionViewModel.loadDescription.value?.get(position)?.description

        return binding?.root
    }

}
```

Он должен получать данные из базы данных `Room` в текстовые поля. Проблема в том, что туда приходит `null`.

`Log "OnClick"` пишет `name во втором фрагменте null`

Но в UseCase что-то всё же приходит (если я правильно понял то, что написано в логе):
`Log "OnClick"` пишет `DescriptionUseCase androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData@20ac29a`

`DataSourceIMPL`:

```
class DataSourceIMPL (private val dao: NameListDao):
    RDDataSource {

    override fun insert(paginationLocalModel: PaginationLocalModel) {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            dao.insert(paginationLocalModel)}
    }

    override fun loadNameList(): LiveData<List<PaginationLocalModel>> {
        return dao.loadNameList()
    }

    override suspend fun clear() {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            dao.clear()}
    }


}
```

`NameListDao`:

```
@Dao
interface NameListDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(paginationLocalModel: PaginationLocalModel)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM pagination_table")
    fun loadNameList() : LiveData<List<PaginationLocalModel>>

    @Query("DELETE FROM pagination_table")
    suspend fun clear()
}
```

`DescriptionRepository`:

```
class DescriptionRepository(private val dataSource: RDDataSource) : DescriptionCall {

    override fun loadDescription(): LiveData<List<PaginationLocalModel>> {
        return dataSource.loadNameList()
      
    }

}
```

`DescriptionUseCase`:

```
class DescriptionUseCase(private val descriptionCall: DescriptionCall) {

    fun loadDescription(): LiveData<List<PaginationLocalModel>> {

        Log.d("OnClick", "DescriptionUseCase " + descriptionCall.loadDescription())
        return descriptionCall.loadDescription()

    }

}
```

`DescriptionViewModel`:

```
class DescriptionViewModel(private val descriptionUseCase: DescriptionUseCase) : ViewModel() {

    val loadDescription = descriptionUseCase.loadDescription()

}
```

`PaginationLocalModel`:

```
@Entity(tableName = "pagination_table")
class PaginationLocalModel (

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    val name: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "date")
    val date: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "description")
    val description: String

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно заменить

```
binding?.name?.text = descriptionViewModel.loadDescription.value?.get(position)?.name
Log.d("OnClick", "name во втором фрагменте " + descriptionViewModel.loadDescription.value?.get(position)?.name)
binding?.date?.text = descriptionViewModel.loadDescription.value?.get(position)?.date
binding?.description?.text = descriptionViewModel.loadDescription.value?.get(position)?.description
```

на

```
descriptionViewModel?.loadDescription?.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {

    binding?.name?.text = it.get(position).name
    binding?.date?.text = it.get(position).date
    binding?.description?.text = it.get(position).description

})
```